# How can I modify the queue in just_audio?

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I'm trying to make a music app using just_audio and audio_service and I'm stuck at implementing the `onAddQueueItem` function. I can't find a way to append/modify the queue on just_audio, only how to reload just_audio with a new playlist via `player.setAudioSource`.

Am I meant to use `player.setAudioSource` to change the current queue or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queues/playlists are achieved in just_audio by creating a `ConcatenatingAudioSource` which gives a list of audio sources to be played one after the other. The [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/just_audio/latest/just_audio/ConcatenatingAudioSource-class.html) for that class lists the methods below, almost all of which deal with appending/modifying the queue:

- add
- addAll
- clear
- insert
- insertAll
- move
- removeAt
- removeRange
- toJson (this one is not relevant)
- toString (this one is not relevant)

So the one you want when implementing `onAddQueueItem` is the first one, `add`:

```dart
Future<void> onAddQueueItem(MediaItem mediaItem) async {
  // Add it to the player
  await concatenatingAudioSource.add(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(mediaItem.id)));
  // Broadcast the state change to clients
  queue.add(mediaItem);
  await AudioServiceBackground.setQueue(queue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've created a variable to hold the ConcatenatingAudioSource. How should I tell just_audio to use this variable?

Comment: It's the same as the very first example of ConcatenatingAudioSource in the README page, i.e. you can pass one of these things into the parameter of `player.load(..here is where you put it..);`.

Comment: Giving this ConcatenatingAudioSource via setAudioSource method stops the audio and resets the progress bar.

Comment: Just to update my previous comment since the `load` method was renamed to `setAudioSource`, the playlist can be initialised via `player.setAudioSource(.. pass in the playlist here ..)`.